OAuth consent screen is necessary for android google sign-in?
I'm developing an Android app with Firebase and Jetpack Compose. My local debug sign-in (emulator and real device) is successful, but only internal testing is failing.
I registered OAuth consent screen unintentionally once, and now the status is pending.
This OAuth consent screen is necessary for Android Google sign-in?
One mysterious point is in the Pre-launch report (Firebase Test Lab). Google sign-in is successful, as I checked the testing video captured.
I tried numerous solutions (Register SHA-1 as fingerprints on Firebase setting of signing key and upload(release) key and debug key, re-download google-services.json, create manually OAuth web client, upgrade Play Console signing key, use GetGoogleIdOption instead of GetSignInWithGoogleOption, etc..), but the problem is still alive.

Ensure you have added the correct SHA-1/SHA-256 fingerprints for all key types (debug, release, and upload keys) in your firebase project settings.

Yeah, I did all. 3 Android client generated and I download google-services.json again.
